Create class with base generic but using derived class
I am trying to write a generic repository in C# that can be re-used for CRUD operations.  I am running into a signature problem while trying to call it.
Consider this base class signature:
public abstract class BaseController<TRepo, TClass> : ControllerBase
    where TRepo : IBaseRepository<TClass>
    where TClass : class {}

When I try to use it, like this:
public class TestController : BaseController<ITestRepository, Case> {}

I get a conversion error from ITestRepository to IBaseRepository even though ITestRepository inherits IBaseRepository as seen here:
public class TestRepository : BaseRepository<Case>, ITestRepository

I'm new to generics, but I think I'm looking for a way to cast a generic derived class as the base class.  Note: I only want to access methods/properties in the base class.

You are using ITestRepository in your code. Don't you mean TestRepository? Won't public class TestController : BaseController<TestRepository, Case> {} work?

This looks like a variance problem, could you add the definition of IBaseRepository<T> and the message of the error you're getting to your question please?

You have defined generic parameter type constraint:
where TRepo : IBaseRepository<TClass>

which means TRepo can be only class inheriting from IBaseRepository<TClass>.
You specified BaseController<ITestRepository, Case>, so you tried to use ITestRepository as TRepo, but it violates your constraint, as ITestRepository DOES NOT inherit from IBaseRepository<TClass>. But TestRepository inherits from both, so it could be used as TRepo generic type parameter.
